# Prevent component from re-rendering when property not used in render function React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am struggling with a component that re-renders. 
I'm using Redux to manage my states. In a component, I'm using a property **(isPlaying: bool)** from my state with mapStateToProps in some methods of my component (class) **except for the render function**, and I use some action creators to dispatch a change for **isPlaying**. By the way, I am using **isPlaying** in another child component(**Music Player**) using connect(react-redux).
**This is what I'm expecting**: 
 When **isPlaying** change, the parent component doesn't re-renders, and the **Music Bar** re-render and I keep using **isPlaying** in my parent component's methods.
**What's the problem**: 
The parent component re-renders even if I'm not using **isPlaying** in the render method. 
Sorry if I did confuse you while reading I am not an English native speaker.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Add a simplified version of the code.
My Initial state:

```
export default {
// Some Irrelevant Properties
...

playlist: {
    isPlaying: false,
    playingTrack: null,
    nextTrack: null,
    prevTrack: null,
    views: null,
    totalListens: null,
    tracks: []
}
```

};

Here's my parent component. (App.js)

```
import ...
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            widgets: [],
            links: [],
            clickedTrack: null
        }

        this.musicBarRef = React.createRef()
        this._isMounted = false;

        // Binding this to the methods used in this Component
        ...

    }
    // All my methods here
    // Example of one function 
    playTrack() {
        let {isPlaying} = this.props
        if (isPlaying) {
            // Pause
        } else {
            // Play
        }
    }

    render() {
        <>
            // Some irrelevant components (don't use isPlaying)
            <TracksPlaylist tracks={this.props.tracks} and some the methods created above />
            <MusicBar ref={this.musicBarRef} and some methods created above />

            // Example of one irrelevant component that re-renders
            <Footer />
        </>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isPlaying: state.playlist.isPlaying,
        selectedTrack: state.playlist.playingTrack,
        nextTrack: state.playlist.nextTrack,
        prevTrack: state.playlist.prevTrack,
        tracks: state.playlist.tracks,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setPlaying: startPlaying, // Set isPlaying: true
    setNotPlaying: stopPlaying, // Set isPlaying: false
    // Some Irrelevent Action Creators
    ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Here's my reducer

```
import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";
import initialState from "./initialState";

export default function musicPlayerReducer(state = initialState.playlist, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        // Some irrelevant cases
        ...

        case types.STOP_PLAYING:
            return {...state, isPlaying: false}
        case types.START_PLAYING:
            return {...state, isPlaying: true}
        case types.NEXT_TRACK_FOUND:
            return {...state, nextTrack: action.track}
        case types.PREV_TRACK_FOUND:
            return {...state, prevTrack: action.track}
        case types.CURRENT_TRACK_FOUND:
            return {...state, playingTrack: action.track}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

TracksPlaylist mentioned in App.js

```
import ...

class TracksPlaylist extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        let {tracks, onPlayClick ... and other methods from App.js} = this.props
        return (
            <div className="songs">
                {
                    Object.values(tracks).length > 0 ?
                        Object.values(tracks).map((item, index) => {
                            return <Track onPlayClick={onPlayClick} key={index} item={item} />
                        }) :
                        ''
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        tracks: state.playlist.tracks,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setPlaying: startPlaying,
    setNotPlaying: stopPlaying,

    // Some irrelevant functions
    ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Tracks)
```

the Track component

```
import ...

class Track extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    hasInteraction(interactionType, trackId) {
        return false
    }


    render() {
        let {onPlayClick, item} = this.props
        return (
            <div key={item.track_id} className="track" id={item.track_id} data-category={item.category_name}>
                    // A lot of irrelevant JSX :)
                    <TrackAction onPlayClick={onPlayClick} item={item} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Track
```

Here's the TrackAction (it uses the isPlaying):

```
import ...

function TrackAction({item, isPlaying, playingTrack, onPlayClick}) {
    return (
        <div className="status action play-track" onClick={onPlayClick}>
            <i id={item.track_id} className={isPlaying && playingTrack.track_id === item.track_id ? 'fas fa-pause' : 'fas fa-play'} />
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isPlaying: state.playlist.isPlaying,
        playingTrack: state.playlist.playingTrack
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TrackAction)
```

I did use TrackAction to make just this component re-render because isPlaying changing and it is registered to this component and used in its render().
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are not using `isPlaying` inside `render` method, you are still subscribing to the change due to `mapStateToProps` binding.

Whenever the `State || Props` changes, React will just re-render the new updated `state || props` with just shallow comparison.

And this is the reason why your parent is getting re-rendered.

One potential solution is to override `shouldcomponentupdate`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output
>   is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default
>   behavior is to re-render on every state change.
>
> Defaults to true. If you override and returns false, then UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(), render(), and componentDidUpdate() will
>   not be invoked.

**Sample code :**

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return <enter_your_condition_to_be_true>; // else false
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it does work for my situation I wrote this expression.
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return this.props.isPlaying === nextProps.isPlaying}